# How do you call a function of a class from another instance of a class?

Tags: python, class

I want to give a class_A properties from another class_B through the class_B functions though it seems to want to get the values from the class_A even though it has not yet been defined. How would you correctly referance the function from class_B?

Here is the code for more insight:

```
# ============== class_A ==============
class Pepper:
   def __init__ (self):
      self.spice_type = "Pepper"
      self.pepper_flavour = ["sharp","pungent"]
   
   def get_type(self):
      return self.spice_type
   
   def get_flavour(self):
      return self.pepper_flavour

class Salt:
   def __init__ (self):
      self.spice_type = "Salt"
      self.salt_flavour = ["salty","bitter"]
   
   def get_type(self):
      return self.spice_type
   
   def get_flavour(self):
      return self.salt_flavour
# ====================================


# ============== class_B ==============
class Spice:
   def __init__(self,type):
      self.spice_type = type
      self.spice_flavor = type.get_flavour(self)
# ====================================


Pepper_Spice = Spice(Pepper)
print(Pepper_Spice.spice_type,Pepper_Spice.spice_flavor)
```

Comment: You're trying to print `Pepper_Spice.type`, but objects of that class do not have that attribute; they have the `spice_type` attribute instead.  As far as I can see, there is no class in your code that has a `type` attribute, so I can't guess what you really meant here.

Comment: This is not a good design.  Surely `Pepper` and `Salt` should just be instances of the `Spice` class, and not separate classes.  `Salt` is a thing of type `Spice`.  It's not a type on its own, unless you plan to have pickling salt, sea salt, etc.  And even if you do keep this, `Salt` and `Pepper` should derive from `Spice`.  They are subtypes, not independent types.

Answer (score 0):

The constructer of Spice class receives class.
So we need to do instantiation to get the resources of the received class' instance as this code.

```
# ============== class_B ==============
class Spice:
   def __init__(self,type):
      tinst = type()
      self.spice_type = tinst.spice_type
      self.spice_flavor = tinst.get_flavour()
```